# Logic: Proving tautological consequence

Tags: logic

I'm having trouble proving this tautological consequence. I'd hope that you guys can maybe oversee my process and identify errors, because I went over this couple of times and I arrive at the same conclusion.

The question goes like this:

> $A \Rightarrow  B$
>
> $C \Rightarrow B$
>
> Therefore: $(A \lor C) \Rightarrow B$
>
> Q: Show that the conclusion of the arguments is a tautological
>   consequence of the premises using truth tables.

This is how I tried to solve it:

[My solution to the problem. It seems like I'm missing something very fundamental here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX40n.png)

Comment: You seem to confusing deduction rules (as used in proofs) with tautologies (statements that are true in all truth assignments). You have decribed a proof rule not a tautology and your attempt tries to show the conclusion is a tautology, which it is not (by itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a truth table of $$((a \rightarrow b) \land (c \rightarrow b)) \rightarrow ((a \lor c) \rightarrow b)$$

instead.

Comment: Just had a quick re-read on the chapter about tautologies and contradiction, now it's all as clear as a day. I arrived at the same proposition and when tested it all came out as a tautology. Thank you for your answer, i'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is really:

A implies B

C implies B is

(A implies B) and (C implies B)

And then it should be easily provable

edit:

\begin{array}{ccc|c@{}ccc@{}ccccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c}
a&b&c&(&a&\lor&c&)&\rightarrow&b&\leftrightarrow&(&a&\rightarrow&b&)&\land&(&c&\rightarrow&b&)\\\hline
1&1&1&&1&1&1&&1&1&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&\\
1&1&0&&1&1&0&&1&1&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&1&&1&&0&1&1&\\
1&0&1&&1&1&1&&0&0&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&0&&0&&1&0&0&\\
1&0&0&&1&1&0&&0&0&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&0&&0&&0&1&0&\\
0&1&1&&0&1&1&&1&1&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&\\
0&1&0&&0&0&0&&1&1&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&1&&1&&0&1&1&\\
0&0&1&&0&1&1&&0&0&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&0&&0&&1&0&0&\\
0&0&0&&0&0&0&&1&0&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&0&
\end{array}

Comment: Why did you rearrange C Implies B is (A implies B) and (C implies B). Am I missing a rule/law here?

Comment: The former are two seperated statements, but I assume you want to check wether if both statements are true, is then (AvC)>B true? Otherwise it makes simply no sense. @Vocaloidas

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, just tried this solution. It doesn't really work.  Fails on the third row where A => B is False and C =>B is False. Following the and rule, the result should also be False.

Comment: @Vocaloidas see edit. it is true, so make a new table